# How do perform conditional ordered logit / probit regression

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I am attempting to model the finishing position (independent variable) of runners in a race based upon height, weight, age, gender, past results (dependent variables). Thusfar I have performed an ordered logit regression from which I can generate predicted probabilities of a runner finishing in a given position. However, the probabilities of all runnings coming first do not sum to one, nor do sum of the probabilities of a runner finishing in any position. So I'm not sure how useful these predicted values are. My preferred software package is Stata, but also have R and Matlab. My best attempt thus far is to run

```
ologit y x1 x2... xn
```

and then scale down the predicted values so they sum to one, but this seems a bit rough and I suspect the resulting numbers are biased in some way. My question is: How do a perform a conditional ordered logit / probit regression?

Comment: What do you mean that the probabilities do not sum to one? Can you paste in some of the problematic output?

Comment: To clarify: Ordered logit regression of runner characteristics on finishing position will generate the predicted probability of a each runner finishing 1st. But the sum of the these probabilities will not necessarily equal 1, unless I force them to be. I know how to force this for regular logit (use clogit command in stata), but not for ordered logit.

Comment: In OLR, the probabilities for all outcomes should sum to 1 for each individual, not the probabilities for all individuals for the same place in the finishing order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example in **R**:

to fit ordered logit model and store results 'm'

```
m <- MASS::polr(y ~ x1 + x2 + xn, data = dat, Hess=TRUE)
```

view a summary of the model

```
summary(m)
```

---

Here's a link to a [detailed walkthrough](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) of ordered logistic regression in **R**.

Comment: Answer needs to be explained more.

Comment: Thanks but that is regular ordered logit - which i can do easily in Stata. I am after conditional ordered logit...